# Concatenated audio clips come out broken

Tags: python, python-3.x, moviepy

I am concatenating a couple of audio clips using moviepy, but every 1/2 times or so, in the place where the files unite, there is a hiss sound or other extra sounds. How can I fix this?
Code:

````py
clips = []
for x in os.listdir(r"{}".format(cwd) + "/SpeechFolder"):
    clips.append(AudioFileClip(r"{}".format(cwd) + "/SpeechFolder/" + x))
    
speech = concatenate_audioclips(clips)```
````

Comment: I have this problem as well. Did you find any solution?

Comment: No I just gave up and started doing them manually

Comment: If you find any let me know

Comment: I gave up as well, and now use another library sox. See example here https://github.com/ErhoSen/RedditVideoMakerBot/blob/master/video_creation/final_video.py#L40-L46